# Entity Framework 4.1 does not drop database when I implement DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a context class that implements DbContext "BeerRecommenderContext" and an intializer that implements

```
DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BeerRecommenderContext>
```

When I run/debug the project, the entity framework does not not drop the old database and create a new one so changes in model are not reflected which causes problems. I then manually delete the database and rerun and the entity framework doesn't create the database. I run it a second time and the entity framework successfully builds the new database. I'm not very familiar with connection strings so it could be an issue there:

```
<add name="BeerRecommenderContext"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
     database=BeerRecommenderContext.mdf;
     AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|BeerRecommenderContext.mdf;
     User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In the Application_Start method of my Global.asax.cs file I have added the line

```
Database.SetInitializer<BeerRecommenderContext>(new BeerRecommenderInitializer());
```

How do I get DropCreateDatabaseAlways to perform properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that adding Database.SetInitializer to the Application_Start to not work every time.

I add a static constructor to the DbContaxt which calls Database.SetInitializer

```
public class BeerRecommenderContext: DbContext
{

    static BeerRecommenderContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BeerRecommenderContext >(new BeerRecommenderInitializer());
    }
}
```